# Problem with a rank of symmetric matrix

Tags: linear-algebra

Let $a$ be $n\times n$ symmetric real matrice, $b$ be a $n\times 1$ real matrice, $c\in \mathbb R$ and let
$
A=\left[ \begin{array}{ll}
a & b\\
b^T &c
\end{array} \right ].
$
I want to know why

1. if $rank(a)=k$, $rank[
   \begin{array}{c} a & b 
   \end{array}
   ]=k$  then $rank(A)$ is $k$ or $k+1$,

and

2. if $rank(a)=k$, $rank[
   \begin{array}{c} a & b 
   \end{array}
   ]=k+1$ then $rank(A)=k+2$.

Thanks

Comment: What are your thoughts on the problem? What have you tried so far?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If $\operatorname{rank}[a\ \ b] = \operatorname{rank}(a)$, then there exists a solution $x$ to the equation $ax = b$. Thus, we can rewrite
$$
A = \pmatrix{a & ax\\ (ax)^T & c} = \pmatrix{a & ax\\ x^Ta & c}.
$$
Now, we perform a "block row-operation" to obtain a matrix of the same rank:
$$
\pmatrix{I & 0\\-x^T & 1}\pmatrix{a & ax\\ x^Ta & c} = \pmatrix{a & ax\\0 & c - x^Tax}
$$
This matrix will have rank $k$ if $c - x^Tax = 0$ and rank $k+1$ if $c - x^Tax \neq 0$.

If $\operatorname{rank}[a\ \ b] = \operatorname{rank}(a) + 1$, then there is no solution to $ax = b$. It follows that the row $[b^T \ \ c]$ is outside the row space of $[a \ \ b]$. Indeed, suppose that there exists a vector $v \in \Bbb R^n$ such that
$$
v^T \pmatrix{a&b} = \pmatrix{b^T & c}.
$$
It follows that $v^Ta = b^T$ and $v^Tb = c$. However, $v^Ta = b^T$ implies that $av = b$, which contradicts our earlier statement that $ax = b$ has no solution.

So, $A$ has rank $k+2$.